# NSMenuItem keyEquivalent width

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

Is there a way of setting keyEquivalent width of NSMenuItem? I've been looking in the documentation and I couldn't find anything.

I set my menuItems programmatically

```
let menuItem = NSMenuItem()
menuItem.keyEquivalent = object.shortcut!
menuItem.title = object.name!
menuItem.representedObject = object
menuItem.action = "testSelector:"               
self.menu.insertItem(menuItem, atIndex: 0)
```

When I open the menu the title is displayed correctly, but it cuts the keyEquivalent (I see 2 characters instead of 3)

I tried setting the minimum width of my menu (and even my NSStatusItem) but all it does is changing the width od the title, and the keyEquivalent stays the same.

Comment: Which shortcut has 3 characters?

Comment: Let say command + option + I ? I'm using MASShortcut in my project to bind keyboard shortcuts to a specific function. Many (if not all of them) are 3 keys shortcut, and I want to display them in the NSMenuIten in keyEquivalent.

Comment: ⌥⌘I is **one** character and **two** modifier keys. There is also a property to set the modifier mask. You should also be aware of that shortcuts defined in an `NSStatusItem` menulet application work only when the application is active.

Comment: Okey, so is the keyEquivalent width settable or not?

Comment: No, because it's not necessary, the total width of modifier keys and key equivalent is calculated automatically.

Comment: I ended up adding custom NSView as NSMenuItem.view :)